# Uncaught TypeError: google.maps.LatLng is not a constructor at init (script.js:7:13)

Tags: html, css, google-maps

please explain why my map is not displayed on the site. Now I have my top bar of the site and a blank white background, but there should be a map. please help me fix it. My API is connected to the project and also billing is connected.
I would also like to help with a question regarding adding a lot of markers to Google maps on my website. I ask for help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Znajdź i zgadnij</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="libs/bootstrap-reboot.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="libs/bootstrap-grid.min.css" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Noto+Sans:ital,wght@0,400;0,700;1,400&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    <style>
      @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Ubuntu:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700&display=swap");
    </style>
    <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
    <script type="module" src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="main">
      <div class="navbar">
        <div class="container">
          <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand"
            >Słupsk<span class="navbar-brand" id="go">Go</span></a
          >
          <div class="navbar-wrap">
            <ul class="navbar-menu">
              <li><a href="zasadygry.html">Zasady gry</a></li>
              <li><a href="kontakt.html"> Kontakt</a></li>
            </ul>
            <a href="mapa.html" class="kontakt">Mapa</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      function initMap() {
        let uluru = { lat: 54.464778, lng: 17.027122 };
        let map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
          zoom: 4,
          center: uluru,
        });
        let marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: uluru, map: map });
      }
    </script>

    <script>
      ((g) => {
        var h,
          a,
          k,
          p = "The Google Maps JavaScript API",
          c = "google",
          l = "importLibrary",
          q = "__ib__",
          m = document,
          b = window;
        b = b[c] || (b[c] = {});
        var d = b.maps || (b.maps = {}),
          r = new Set(),
          e = new URLSearchParams(),
          u = () =>
            h ||
            (h = new Promise(async (f, n) => {
              await (a = m.createElement("script"));
              e.set("libraries", [...r] + "");
              for (k in g)
                e.set(
                  k.replace(/[A-Z]/g, (t) => "_" + t[0].toLowerCase()),
                  g[k]
                );
              e.set("callback", c + ".maps." + q);
              a.src = `https://maps.${c}apis.com/maps/api/js?` + e;
              d[q] = f;
              a.onerror = () => (h = n(Error(p + " could not load.")));
              a.nonce = m.querySelector("script[nonce]")?.nonce || "";
              m.head.append(a);
            }));
        d[l]
          ? console.warn(p + " only loads once. Ignoring:", g)
          : (d[l] = (f, ...n) => r.add(f) && u().then(() => d[l](f, ...n)));
      })({ key: "AIzaSyDgKBm5DUC", v: "weekly" });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```